# Deleted rows before a date but it deleted everything

Tags: mysql, limit, sql-delete, delete-row

I ran the following query to do some data cleanup:

```
use database;
delete
from database
where Date < '2017-08-16'
limit 10000000;
```

I used the limit to break it into chunks so that I could monitor progress.  I ran

```
select *
from database
order by Date
limit 10;
```

to confirm the older data was being removed.  On the final time, it had only about a month left, but I ran the original query anyways since I figured it would hit the WHERE restriction and stop.  The query completed and now when I select * it returns zero row.  What happened?  How can I properly clean up older rows without this happening? (Fortunately the data is backed up but I need a proper method for removing old rows).

Comment: Is your Date column stored as a date / timestamp or is it a varchar?

Comment: LIMIT without ORDER BY is almost meaningless.

Comment: @Strawberry your comment is not relevant to this problem. The OP wants to delete *all* rows < '2017-08-16', so the order doesn't matter.

Comment: My data is stored as Date datatype.  

My understanding is that LIMIT should offer no problems if using a WHERE statement.  For example if you query limit 3 where num = 1 and your rows are 1, 1, 2, 1 it will only return 1,1 because first 3 rows were within limit of query, and only the first two satisfied the where clause.  Based on that, the above query should have worked.  Could it be something else?

Comment: @BillKarwin Frankly, I'm not at all clear *what* the question is. Please enlighten us.

Comment: @AaronMartin, should we assume that your original data had at least some rows with date >= '2017-08-16'? Because if all the data was less than that date, and you deleted all of it, then you'd of course end up with zero rows.

Comment: @BillKarwin Yes, the table has a few hundred rows for every day.

Comment: Well you obviously ran some different query than the one you post above, because `database` is a reserved word. I'm going to guess you accidentally forgot a where clause. Check your query history.

Comment: @BillKarwin I just substituted the word database for my actual database name to sanitize the data, I just have a habit of doing that.  If it matters the name of the database was deptSalesData.  I copied and pasted the query from MySQL Workbench, it is most assuredly correct.

Comment: Although I might be stating the obvious (and repeat what Bill already said, but without the emphasize): are you really sure you meant to delete `Date < '2017-08-16'`. That is *TODAY*, not last month. Especially if that was a backup from yesterday, it might only contain data from up to yesterday.

Comment: Oh good god.  Thanks that was an embarrassing oversight.  I upvoted both of you, it won't let me mark you as an answer I guess since it is a comment.  Please post as an answer so I can give you credit.